# How to keep a daemon running in `.devcontainer` setup?

Tags: linux, docker, daemon, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I have a `devcontainer.json` which contains the following in

```json
{
  "name": "Dev Container",
  "dockerComposeFile": [
    "docker-compose.yaml"
  ],
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
  "service": "dev",
  "postStartCommand": [
    ".devcontainer/setup/run-at-start.sh"
  ],
  "remoteUser": "ci"
}
```

where `run-at-start.sh` contains:

```bash
url=https://www.server.com
# git config --global "credential.$url.useHttpPath" true
git config --global --unset-all credential.$url.helper || true
git config --global --add "credential.$url.helper" ""
git config --global --add "credential.$url.helper" "cache --socket=$HOME/.cache/git/credential/socket0"

# This starts the daemon.
echo
{
    echo "protocol=https"
    echo "host=www.server.com"
    echo "path="
    echo "username=banana"
    echo "password=general"
} | git credential approve

printf "protocol=https\nhost=www.server.com\n" | git credential fill
```

the `postStartCommand`. The container starts up and I see the credentials popping out on the credentials from `git credential fill` but after the `postStartCommand` has finished and I log into the container with

```bash
devcontainer exec --workspace-folder . bash
```

I dont see any `git-credential-cache` daemon running. It seems it has already exited...

I am not sure, but when I log into the container and run the **same script** and logout and back into it again with `docker exec ... bash`, the credential manager is still running and the `git credential fill` prints the credentials which where approved...

Somehow it does not stay running when `devcontainer` runs `postStartCommand`. The container user is `ci` and the daemon runs as `ci` as I see from `ps`.

How can I make this happen? I tried to play around `setsid` and `disown` etc...